# Keyframe animation removing skew from div on animation

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a skew transform applied to a div and I'm wanting to animate it on page load.

When I use the a keyframe animation, the skew is removed during the animation and then "pops" into place once the animation is complete.

How can I keep the skew applied to the div while the animation is in progress?

```css
div {
  -webkit-transform:skew(-197deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(-197deg);
  transform:skew(-197deg);
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, this is a skewed div that does not stay skewed when the animation is in progress.</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `skew` to the animation or else the animation rule will overwrite it.

```css
div {
  -webkit-transform:skew(-197deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(-197deg);
  transform:skew(-197deg);
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: skew(-197deg) translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: skew(-197deg) translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, this is a skewed div that does not stay skewed when the animation is in progress.</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see. Since I was transforming the div in the animation it was overriding the other transform. Thanks for the answer!